# elasticsearch date range get yesterday

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking a way to get the data from "yesterday"
instead of:

```
"range" : {
    "price" : {
        "gt" : "2014-11-24",
        "lt" : "2014-11-26"
    }
}
```

I would like something like:

```
"range" : {
    "price" : {
        "eq" : "2014-11-25"
    }
}
```

Does anybody think it could be possible?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
"range" : {
    "price" : {
        "gt" : "now-2d",
        "lt" : "now"
    }
}
```

But I would like to get data from **00:00 am** to  **00:00 pm**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "price": {
        "gte": "now-1d/d",
        "lt": "now/d"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: this would return null. It should be `now-2d/d` instead of `1`; or you could change `gt` to `gte` to fix it.

Comment: Isn't @Xiao right? The answer didn't work for me until I changed it to `gte`, I think it should be edited.

Answer (score 6):

The answer from @andrei-stefan is the way to do this, but I wanted to add a little extra example for other people hitting this question.

If you wanted to get data from yesterday between 12:00pm and 1:00pm rather than the whole day, you could do that with a little more date math:

```
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "price": {
        "gt": "now-1d/d+12h",
        "lt": "now-1d/d+13h"
      }
    }
  }
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math

Comment: I am grateful for your extended example: I was creating a query for the period "now-2d/d" to "now-1d/d", but was getting matches at 16:00 the day before — turns out that the data is in GMT, but the query is being performed in PST. With "now-2d/d+8h" and "now-1d/d+8h", I'm getting exactly the right data.

I will have to remind myself to change 8h to 7h when DST begins, of course.

Comment: ^ Correction: It's not that the data is GMT, but that day-rounding (/d) uses 00:00 UTC.

Comment: @DaveLand That's a good point. It's good to keep your dates in UTC in databases and server-side, then transform them to local time when they get to the client. Kibana shows stuff in local time, even though it's UTC in elastic.

Answer (score 0):

Better to add timezone. For example if you are in CST6CDT then to fetch data from 00:00 to 23:59 use this code -

```
"query": {
    "range": {
      "price": {
        "gt": "now/d-1d/d",
        "lt": "now/d-1d/d",
        "time_zone":"CST6CDT"
      }
    }
  }
```